# Where to find input placeholder style

Tags: html, css

Couldn't find default placeholder style for input element.
There are no any `webkit-input-placeholder`, `-moz-placeholder`, `-moz-placeholder`, or `-ms-input-placeholder` style settings in any css files.

UPDATE: Guys, don't hurry to judge me.
I have the legacy code (tones of css files).  The one placeholder style (font-weight, color and so on) is not properly shown in IE 11. I started to find where the placeholder style is defined. And I didn't find any placeholder style declaration you all mentioned.
So I assume there is a default style for placeholder in browser.

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to style placeholders, he wants to know what the default browser styles are for placeholders. That's like asking what's the default styles for `html` or `body` or `div` tags. Every browser sets some defaults in the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: You can find here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Webkit's User Agent Stylesheet (Chrome & Safari) can be found here: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

Their CSS shows:

```
::placeholder {
  -webkit-text-security: none;
   color: darkGray;
  pointer-events: none !important;
}

input::placeholder, isindex::placeholder {
  white-space: pre;
  word-wrap: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I can't find any other sources that have the defaults for other browsers, but I imagine they would be close to this.

Comment: As stated in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-placeholder#Browser_compatibility) : "Firefox applies a default style of `opacity: 0.54` to placeholder text."

Comment: Nice find, I think it's safe to assume then that Firefox placeholder text uses the default color (black) combined with this opacity to produce grey text.

Comment: Yep you can see this by adding `::-moz-placeholder { opacity:1; }` in your CSS  (see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8770moe5/))

Comment: notably, i believe the pseudo element `::placeholder` is only for newer browsers

Answer (score 0):

To style the place holders you should use `vendor-prefixed selectors`

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}
```

You can even scope the elements,

```
input[type="email"].user_email::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

Please refer this answer, [Different place holder implementations and usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css/2610741#2610741)

Answer (score 0):

Please do refer the style for PlaceHolder...

```
<input    placeholder='hello'/> <br />
<textarea placeholder='hello'></textarea>
```

For Example

```
/* do not group these rules */
*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
*:-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 4-18 */
    color: red;
}
*::-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 19+ */
    color: red;
}
*:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder styling supported by a lot of browsers,
look here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Example -

Style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input:-ms-input-placeholder {
       color:pink;
       font-style:italic;
       text-transform:uppercase;
       text-align:center;
    }

    input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color:pink;
       font-style:italic;
       text-transform:uppercase;
       text-align:center;
    }

    input:-moz-placeholder {
       color:pink;
       font-style:italic;
       text-transform:uppercase;
       text-align:center;
    }

    /* firefox 19+ */
    input::-moz-placeholder {
       color:pink;
       font-style:italic;
       text-transform:uppercase;
       text-align:center;
    }
      </style>
```

HTML:

```
      <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text" size="40">
```

working code on Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/bpTg4zIQfGD580XKo7q8?p=preview