# Change placeholder text color

Tags: css, forms

I've tried unsuccessfully to change the Placeholder color on the payment form on the homepage of this site - http://schoolaccounting.ng/

The form just below the image of the lady. I'd appreciate any pointers on anything I can try here.

I've tried targeting the color attribute on the form itself, and while the color of written text complies, the placeholder remains white. I have also tried suggestions from this thread - [Where to find input placeholder style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435036/where-to-find-input-placeholder-style/38435120#38435120)

Comment: You might try the `::placeholder` pseudo element. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Answer (score 2):

try these:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Oh, got confused with the last comment, so i'll try again - Did you copied it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38435120/754119 ? This should be flagged as duplicate, this question was asked a lot of times before

Comment: I've actually tried this and several other suggestions from this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435036/where-to-find-input-placeholder-style/38435120#38435120 but none of them have worked so far. I've been on this for at least a day now

Comment: Make sure you don't have overriding styles by adding '!important' @OsobaOsaze